How can I automate capture of output of last command in iTerm2?
iTerm2 has a feature that lets you right click on the output of a command and then select "Copy" to copy the entire output of the last command including the command itself to the clipboard. This is a great feature.
However, it would be even greater if it wasn't so mouse intensive. I'd like to just hit a hot key and have the content the last command go right to the clipboard.
I looked at the Python API but nothing really jumped out at me for how I might approach this problem.

Have you tried pbcopy & pbpaste commands?
history : lists all the prior commands
!history_number: previous execution of the history

!history_number|pbcopy (hit enter)

It will show the actual command along with **pbcopy** (hit enter again)

pbpaste or 

pbpaste>file.txt



Thanks but I need the output of the command.

@StevieD you can export the contents of pbpaste>file.txt  to get the output of the command.

@Evert This solution neither gives me the output of the last command or the output of the original command. This reruns the command. I don't want to rerun the last command. I need the output of the last command. And I didn't downvote anyone.

@StevieD alright, well it's good to clarify that because imho it was a reasonable workaround even if it wasn't exactly what you asked. People are taking the time to come up with solutions.
